# display json from php in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

hello guys i have tired alots of way to display json like this example below i want to sperate the id and the question_content then array of choices all this in jsone_encode and the json can take one parameter as i try how this work my php code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username =  "root";
$password = "123456789";
$dbName = "quiz";

//Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT id, qustion_content,A,B,C FROM question";
//$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Type, Cost FROM items";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //show data for each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        echo "".json_encode($row[id],$row[question_content]'answer',array( $row[A],$row[B],$row[C]))) . "";

}

?>
```

```js
{
    "id": 0,
    "qustion_content": "Questionsample",
    "choices": [
        "Choice 1",
        "Choice 2",
        "Choice 3"
    ],
    "answer": 2
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read the [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php) manual page and pay particular attention to the _Parameters_ section and examples

Comment: you should use $row['id'] instead $row[id] you should build you array and then use this array as a parameter for json_encode

Comment: if the answer was helpful for you don't forget to click on green flag to close question

Answer (score 2):

you should build your array and then send it to jason_encode

```
$row['id'] = 0;
$row['A'] = 'Choice 1';
$row['B'] = 'Choice 2';
$row['C'] = 'Choice 3';
$row['qustion_content'] = 'Questionsample';
$row['answer'] = 2;

$choices = array($row['A'],$row['B'],$row['C']);
$arr = array('id' => $row['id'], 'qustion_content' => $row['qustion_content'], 'choices' => $choices, 'answer' => 2);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: it works but there no Comma between json objects when i copy the output to json online view its say must be },{ like this

Comment: {"id":"0","question":"question zero","test":["answer1","answer2","answer3"]}{"id":"1","question":"the first question test","test":["k1","k2","k3"]} it should split between objects by Comma for that when i copy my json output its say invalid

Comment: {"id":6,"qustion_content":4,"choices":[1,2,3],"answer":2}

Comment: json_encode insert the commas